# Using other person's docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, consul

I am new to docker and while I was searching for something related to my project, I found a popular container on dockerhub -> https://hub.docker.com/r/augury/haproxy-consul/dockerfile.
This may solve the problem that I was facing before. My question is how do I use it? Do I simply run this container, register my applications on consul and this will handle the rest, or something else.
Is it like npmjs.org, where we simply import libraries and use them?

Comment: If you want to run this docker file, you just need to keep it in your workspace by the name of 'Dockerfile', when you build a image, this will be built and then you can start your container.

Comment: Is this what you need ? 1) Install and configure docker
2) If necessary pulll the image
3) Issue a "docker run"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea of docker is that its a replication of images in which you can make modifications,so go ahead and build a container of the said project.Changes or any form of modifications will remain yours(your container) until you push it to a repo(upstream).For how to use it just go to the docker docs for more info on how to use it.Hope this helps.

Comment: So, let me give an example with respect to this image to understand if I got this correct. I pull this image, run it, and in this container, HaProxy and Consul-template are present. On my machine, I have 2 applications which register to consul and consul template builds a config file. So, I simply have to run the applications, give the port exposted by the container (consul) to these applications and it should run.  In a nutshell, the container has all the elements required, I just have to get the address which can be exposed in my local environment.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply pull the image `docker pull augury/haproxy-consul` and run using `docker run augury/haproxy-consul -p 80:80`. the container will be running and accessible on 80(2nd port)

And also, You can use the image as a base image in your DockerFile if you want to add something on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good idea of how the docker runs.Use the port created to make all your modifications, and yes all the changes are on your local repo.